# Strange SSL_read() erro : SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL , but errno is 0

Tags: c, openssl, connection

My program is using openssl1.1.1f, runing at Android 10 platform , When SSL connection is establish for a while , and SSL_read() is working fine, after a while, SSL_read() return -1, and SSL_get_error() get SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, but When I print errno , I got errno==0,  I am not sure what was happen

Comment: Maybe the  peer connection close the connection. Check the state of the connection.

Comment: peer close (FIN RST) would be 103 104 read from  errno ,  is there any other type that will cause errno set to 0 ??

Comment: You should provide more detail information to get more accurate answer. There are a lot of factor  that lead to this state. I suppose that get a dump from tcp packets are transfer  through established session.

Comment: i am working on it, but it doesn't happen again, is there any system-level factors lead to this, rather than  TCP packet??

Comment: I don't think so. You could also check setting of keepalive parameters.